# rsnapshot over NFS issue

Tags: backup, nfs

I have a VPS configured with a webhost which I need to backup regularly. I have also purchased a 'backup disk' which is simply an NFS mount on another of their servers.

I have configured rsnapshot to run 4hourly | daily | weekly backups and another script to tar the backups into daily archives with logs.

My issue is that the NFS share is mounted with **root_squash** option, meaning that my files/dirs all have nobody:nobody permissions. This causes problems with my scripts in that rsnapshot regularly fails with "permission denied" errors when incrementally syncing the files/dirs .

Is there any workaround for this or does anybody recommend a better backup solution for regular incremental backups to an NFS share?

Comment: same problem without root_squash option, also have errors with permissions preserving

Answer (score 0):

Check out if [Obnam](http://liw.fi/obnam/) would suit you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/).

> Duplicity backs directories by producing encrypted tar-format volumes
>   and uploading them to a remote or local file server. Because duplicity
>   uses librsync, the incremental archives are space efficient and only
>   record the parts of files that have changed since the last backup.
>   Because duplicity uses GnuPG to encrypt and/or sign these archives,
>   they will be safe from spying and/or modification by the server.